# Practical consequences of choice of source port for UDP transmission? Should be zero?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, port, raw-sockets

The description for the UDP source port field in the Wikipedia reads:

> This field identifies the sender's port when meaningful and should be
>   assumed to be the port to reply to if needed. If not used, then it
>   should be zero. If the source host is the client, the port number is
>   likely to be an ephemeral port number. If the source host is the
>   server, the port number is likely to be a well-known port number.

I am using raw sockets to transmit a UDP packet and wondering how I should fill this in. The process is a client only, so there is no "reply" port. Should I just leave it as zero, or is there a specific value that needs to be looked up? What are the practical consequences of the source port value? For example, if I put a random value in the field would it make any difference?

Comment: UDP relies on ports. You can't send a UDP packet to port 0. Binding a UDP socket to port 0 will cause the OS to pick a random ephemeral port to use instead. If you use a RAW socket bound to an interface, and there is no bound port for it, you can specify 0 as the sender port if you don't expect a reply to be sent back. Otherwise, use a real port that is listening for inbound UDP data (or just use a UDP socket instead of a RAW socket)

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is for the source address, not the destination address. When transmitting raw packets, no source port is bound. It's just a field in the header that gets filled in.

Comment: I know what you meant. I stick by what I said earlier, but let me reword a couple of things: "Binding a UDP socket to source port 0 will cause the OS to pick a random ephemeral port to send from...  If you use a RAW socket bound to an interface, there is no source port for it to put in the packets, so you can specify 0 as the source port if you don't expect a reply to be sent back from the receiver."